# How to enable Pan and Zoom in a QGraphicsView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, zooming, qgraphicsview

I am using python and Qt Designer to implement loading tiff images and to enable Pan and Zoom on some mouse event (wheel - zoom, press wheel - pan).

I was looking into some options and classes that can work with images etc, and so far I have found:

> QGraphicsScene, QImage, QGraphicsView

I have three classes (just testing)

1. *ViewerDemo* which have *QGraphicsView* element:

   ```
       """description of class"""
       # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GraphicsViewdemo.ui'
       try:
       _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
       except AttributeError:
           def _fromUtf8(s):
               return s
           class Ui_Dialog(object):
               def setupUi(self, Dialog):
                   Dialog.setObjectName(("Dialog"))
                   Dialog.resize(500, 500)
               self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(Dialog)
               self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
               self.graphicsView.setObjectName(("graphicsView"))
               self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
               QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
           def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
               Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None,
   QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
   ```
2. *MyForm* class, that is *QDialog*, where I call class *ViewerDemo*, loading Image, and put image into *QGraphicsView*

   ```
       import sys
       from ViewerDemo import *
       from PyQt4 import QtGui
       class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
           def __init__(self, url, parent=None):
               QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)


               self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
               self.ui.setupUi(self)
               self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
              self.image = QtGui.QImage(url)
               pixmap= QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image)
               item=QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
               self.scene.addItem(item)
               self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
               self.scale = 1
               QtCore.QObject.connect(self.scene, QtCore.SIGNAL('mousePressEvent()'),self.mousePressEvent)

       def mousePressEvent(self, event):
           print ('PRESSED : ',event.pos())
   ```

(3) is just where the application is executing:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
    import sys
    from MyForm import MyForm
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        url = "D:/probaTiff"
        myapp = MyForm(url)
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found how to do something on mouse-click (left and wheel click), to print pixel coordinates (I will need that to get the coordinates in the Coordinate System of the picture WGS84, for example).

What I need more, is how to zoom picture (wheel or double click, whatever) and to pan picture (holding left mouse click or holding wheel).

Or, is there some better Qt classes for doing this, and some better way
Can you help me please?

This is what I have so far with this code

[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is not too difficult to do using the built in capabilities of `QGraphicsView`.

The demo script below has left-button panning and wheel zoom (including anchoring to the current cursor position). The `fitInView` method has been reimplemented because the built in version adds a weird fixed margin that can't be removed.

PyQt6 version:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPointF)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom <= 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.position().toPoint()))
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

PyQt5 version:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom <= 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt4 version:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class PhotoViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.delta() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom <= 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you very much. You did everything. 
Just one question. How can I remove mouse cursor 'hand'? I just want to show hand when I hold left-click (just when I want to pan)?
And second question, how add some vector graphic, and put on some pixel on picture?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: And one more question. How to set that my QGraphicsView dont be greater than picture. Because when I click I get pixel position on Viewer and sometimes there is not picture. I need pixel position of picture element not on Viewer. Help?

Comment: On the mouse cursor: I suppose you could set the drag-mode on mouse-down/mouse-up or something. As for the other issues: please ask new questions.

Comment: Ok. I enable drag-mode on mousePressed, and on double-click, i use function mapToScene to find koordinates of scene. Thank you very much.

Comment: just one more question. It's related with Zoom option. How to see image scale (1:1000, 1:2500) etc. If You know what I mean,

Comment: @milutinke. Just use `self.scale(factor, factor)` with whatever scaling factor you like.

Comment: I have a problem. When I add mouseMoveEvent function, then my zoom on wheel doesnt work well :/... What is the problem? :/ Thanks @ekhumoro

Comment: @milutinke. It's hard to debug invisible code. Maybe you need to call the base-class method: `super(PhotoViewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)`. If that doesn't work, ask a new question, and show the actual code.

Comment: yes, I allready done that. QGraphicsView.moseMoveEvent(event)... Thanks any way! @ekhumoro

Comment: This is an incredible answer, with a lot of work put into making the cleanest solution for the question. I needed to implement zoom, drag, and rotate, and was able to use your PhotoViewer class as a jumping off point. Thank you! I implemented rotate feature by overriding contextMenuEvent.

Comment: Hi, ekhumoro! You answer so great! I have one question if I send a few pictures in the scene (it's my task, I create a mini-player for myself, and I have an array of pixmaps). How I can "save" the settings which I set in previous picture? That's it, I won't save zoom for the next pixmaps, how I can do that? Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: @antipups Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but something like: keep the current zoom and then do `self.scale(factor, factor)` when setting the next photo instead of `self.fitInView()`. See `wheelEvent` for how the zoom works (it's not complicated).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I solve my problem yet! But your answer is awesome, cause I waste a 7 hours on this problem!

Comment: Great answer, this is so helpful! I solved a small bug in the PyQt5 version, maybe in the other versions as well. If you zoom out and then make the window larger, you can't zoom out until you zoomed in for a bit. You can solve this easily by replacing `elif self._zoom == 0:` by `elif self._zoom <= 0:` inside `wheelEvent()`

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I can't reproduce that behaviour on my arch-linux system, but I amended all the code examples anyway since it shouldn't have any other side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to open TIFF files up to several gigabytes with ordinary PIL (pillow) library. It is not quite easy, but it works.

You could see the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137257/7550928), second example after bold **EDIT** string could open, move and zoom TIFF files.

Answer (score 0):

I post here the working code of the proposed solution by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) for **PyQt6** and **python 3.9**. Before running be sure to have image.jpg in the directory.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPointF)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.position().toPoint()))

        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, posi):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag:

            self.editPixInfo.setText('{0:04.0f}, {0:04.0f}'.format(posi.x(), posi.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please explain how this improves on the other answer, it's not clear by just looking at your answer

Comment: It was just to be compatible with PyQt6. The already proposed code does not work with the said version of PyQt. Hope it clarifies the reason why I posted here this answer.