# PyQt5: In a QGraphicsView, rebind ScrollHandDrag to work with middle mouse button, not just left mouse button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm working on a map editor, where I use a `QGraphicsView` to display a `QGraphicsObject` (the map). I have already implemented the image zoom functionality from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508711/how-to-enable-pan-and-zoom-in-a-qgraphicsview), and I have tried using their implementation of pan, and have found that it works. However, I want to be able to do the pan without toggling, simply by holding down the middle mouse button and dragging from there.

I've written this code to switch between the two modes (normal and drag), and then call it on `mouse(Press/Release)Events`.

(in QGraphicsView)

```
def toggleDragMode(self):
    if self.dragMode() == QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        self.pointerMode = PointerMode.Normal
    else:
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.pointerMode = PointerMode.Drag

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() & Qt.MiddleButton:
        self.toggleDragMode()
    ...
    super().mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if self.dragMode() == QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        self.pointerMode = PointerMode.Normal
    super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

(Sidenote: With the `mouseReleaseEvent`, I found that I couldn't use `event.buttons() & Qt.MiddleButton` to check if the middle button was released, so I always check and release in this case.)

However, whenever I try and middle-click and drag, no pan happens. However, I have confirmed this works correctly whenever I use the left mouse button as the binding (i.e. `if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton: toggleDrag()`). There has to be some code in `QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent()` that checks to see if the left button is held AND the cursor is in DragMode. Is there a way to change the keybinding on that deeper level?

EDIT: I just found [this link](http://tomcowland.com/katana/archives/460) and tried it by doing this (in `QGraphicsView`)

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
  ...
  self.STOP_GLOBAL_SCROLLING = 1
```

But to no avail. Still, it's an interesting lead.