# PyQt5 App built with PyInstaller doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt5, executable, pyinstaller, macos-mojave

- `MacOS 10.14`
- `Python 3.7.1`
- `PyInstaller` lates version downloaded from `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip` on 24 sept 2019

I'm trying to build an app with `PyQt5` and `PyInstaller`. I could successfully do this with the following small script (**Script 1**): after I cd the directory where the script resides, I just ran the `PyInstaller script.py`. It then built the app and I could find the executable in the new created subdirectory `path/to/script/dist/script/` In this directory there is an executable that you can double click and the app runs. I then tried to do the same with a bigger script (**Script 2**, called `image_viewer_24_02_2019.py` for the error message) which I found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508711/how-to-enable-pan-and-zoom-in-a-qgraphicsview/35514531#35514531). I then tried to run the executable (in `path/to/script/dist/script/`) but I got the following **Error message**. What could be the source of the problem when building the **Script 2**?

Note, the problem persisted after installing the latest version with `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

Here are sequentially: **Script 1** (which could be successfully built), **Script 2** (which could not be built) and its **Error message**:

**Script 1** (which could be successfully built)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        title = QLabel("Hello World from PyQt", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

**Script 2** (could could be built, but the app doesn't work)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(QtCore.QPoint(event.pos()))
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Error message** (after launching the app created with **script 2**)

```
Last login: Sun Feb 24 14:39:36 on ttys001
You have new mail.
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/mymac/Documents/PyQt/image_viewer_24_02_2019/build/image_viewer_24_02_2019/image_viewer_24_02_2019 ; exit;
(base) mymacs-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$ /Users/mymac/Documents/PyQt/image_viewer_24_02_2019/build/image_viewer_24_02_2019/image_viewer_24_02_2019 ; exit;
[45194] Error loading Python lib '/Users/mymac/Documents/PyQt/image_viewer_24_02_2019/build/image_viewer_24_02_2019/libpython3.7m.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/mymac/Documents/PyQt/image_viewer_24_02_2019/build/image_viewer_24_02_2019/libpython3.7m.dylib, 10): image not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: change `image.jpg` to full path `/path/of/image.jpg`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @eyllanesc. So what I did is that, 16 lines before the end of the script, I changed the line `self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg'))` to `self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('/path/of/image.jpg'))`. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. Does this correspond to the change you were thinking of or I misunderstood?